# Awesome Window Manager and keyboard settings

Tags: ubuntu, awesome

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 and I have installed Awesome on top of it. To configure some settings I am still using unity-control-center, however I just noticed that whatever I put into keyboard settings (notably how fast I can type, delay between key presses and similar) is basically ignored.

Where/how can I set/change the keyboard settings so the are not ignored?

Comment: Are you talking about the keyboard repeat delay?  That is controlled by `xset`.  Possible duplicate:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/140255/how-to-override-the-new-limited-keyboard-repeat-rate-limit

Comment: In my opinion it's not a duplicate, however second answer works for me. gsettings is ignored by awesome and it explains why changing values via unity-control-center does nothing. However xset does a trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verbatim copy of this answer:  [How to override the new limited keyboard repeat rate limit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140255/how-to-override-the-new-limited-keyboard-repeat-rate-limit)

You can temporarily override Ubuntu's max keyboard rate using the xset command if you're using GNOME 3 on Ubuntu > 10.04. Example:

```
xset r rate 220 160
```

You can also try adding (uncomenting) the following in `/etc/kbd/config`:

```
KEYBOARD_RATE="160"

KEYBOARD_DELAY="220"
```